# how to stop a google apps script - have already revoked permissions

Tags: google-apps-script

I ran the Drive Migrator script to try to move some files between 2 google accounts.  It failed and kept sending me error emails, so I tried to turn it off by by revoking the Drive Migrator permissions inside my google account settings.  Now I get a different email every day, saying that Drive Migrator failed to run because it requires authorization, so it is still running somewhere but I can't find any reference to it in my google account settings.  The error email contains a link where I am supposed to be able to configure triggers for the script, but the link just loads a "Forbidden Error 403" page.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Google Apps Script (can be any script). Remove any triggers that fire the migrator. Revoking the permissions would only cause an error message to be sent out, as the script will try to run due to the trigger. It tries to get through the oAuth and fails, causing you to receive the error.

A trigger is the only thing you need the script to **attempt** to run. Authorization is needed to actually perform **some** of the tasks in the script. Heck, some scripts can be run automatically with no authorization whatsoever. Always get rid of any triggers you no longer need.

Comment: thank you.  In my case, I didn't actually have any scripts that I had created myself, but I got to the script editor by loading any spreadsheet and navigating to the triggers, as outlined below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go here:
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Scroll down and select "Drive Migrator" then select "Remove".

(It was mentioned in the app reviews)

Comment: Thanks, but I've done that already, which is why I'm getting the "requires authorization" error emails now.

Comment: then try this: goto your google drive and delete any file which is named drive migrator.

Comment: there isn't any.  There were 2 files in my drive - the getting started pdf and the sheet generated by the migrator to output its log.  I deleted this but I doubt that will help.

Comment: do NOT delete any files (as suggested above) as it will make it harder to recover. instead, google for how to list all your script triggers and delete the drive migrator trigger.

Comment: @ZigMandel  the trigger should be irrelevant if the permissions have already been revoked.

Comment: not at all, thats precisely his issue because the trigger will send a failure email.

Comment: thank you @ZigMandel that fixed it.  For others, load any spreadsheet in your Drive and choose "Tools / Script editor" and then "Resources / All your triggers"

Answer (score 0):

I went to the respective script and just added /* and */

/*

```
script here
```

*/